# What is the rule to eliminate (Z AND NEG Z) in this formula?

Tags: propositional-calculus, disjunctive-normal-form

Please give me a hint how I came from the left to the right side?

$$(X \land Y) \lor (Z \land \neg Z) \lor (Z \land X) \Leftrightarrow (X \land Y) \lor (Z \land X)$$

Comment: Use the Law of Excluded Middle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle

Comment: No, @enedil that is the [Law of Non-Contradction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_noncontradiction). $\vdash \neg(\varphi\wedge\neg \varphi)$ . Which is similar, but not the same; please don't confuse them.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Yes, I'm ashamed for my sloppiness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the complement laws and identity laws
$$p\wedge\neg p\equiv F$$
$$p\vee F\equiv p$$
Coming to the question,
$$(X \land Y) \lor (Z \land \neg Z) \lor (Z \land X) \Leftrightarrow (X \land Y) \lor (Z \land X)$$

Note that $(Z \land \neg Z)$ can be compared with $(p\wedge\neg p)\equiv F$,

so $(Z \land \neg Z)=F$

Now we have,

$$(X \land Y) \lor F \lor (Z \land X) $$and this can be compared with $p\vee F\equiv p$ which gives $(X \land Y) \lor (Z \land X) $

So,
$$(X \land Y) \lor (Z \land \neg Z) \lor (Z \land X) \Leftrightarrow (X \land Y) \lor (Z \land X)$$

Comment: It should be $$p\vee F\equiv p$$

Comment: @Bram28 Thanks, I edited it.

Comment: You have it on the third line from bottom as well ...

Answer (score 1):

$z \land \lnot z$ is just $\bot$, "falsum", and $x \lor \bot \Leftrightarrow x$ for all $x$, as is clear from truth tables.

Comment: Do you have a truth table where I can find this?

Comment: @user3352632 it’s obvious, really.